# Disable/enable text field with radio button (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, onclick, switch-statement, radio-button, textfield

thanks for the past help. I am asking you again.

I want to have 2 radio buttons, which will change the state (Enabled/Disabled) of a text input.

I managed to make it come from disabled to enabled, but the problem is, that when you are switching between radio buttons, the text fields remains Enabled. And I do not want that.

html is in fiddle

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#casodhoda,#casodhoda1').prop('disabled',true);
$('input[type=radio][name=radioknof1]').click( function(){
$('#casodhoda,#casodhoda1').prop('disabled',true).val('');
$(this).next('span').children('wpcf7-form-control-wrap casodhoda').prop('disabled',false).triggerHandler('focus');
});
});
```

EDIT, modified a little the code, and on any way cannot get to working solution anymore.. I want the input fields to be disabled at load, and when user clicks on radio it should enable both and focus on first input field. The http://jsfiddle.net/wLFKD/3/ is here. Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle is completely different from what you ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completely changed as per your sites html. This should work:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#casodhoda,#casprihoda').prop('disabled',true);
  $('input[type=radio][name=radioknof]').click( function(){
    $('#casodhoda,#casprihoda').prop('disabled',true).val('');
    $(this).next('span').children('.wpcf7-form-control').prop('disabled',false).triggerHandler('focus');
  });
});
```

There was a typo.
If this doesn't work, the only other way I can think of is to... No, I think this will work.

Comment: thanks! It works, I cannot vote for your answer. The other working solution is http://jsfiddle.net/VV9Fu/2/

Comment: hey, can you help me one more time.. I cannot get it to work on my site (transferji.org).. I also tried this fiddle (jsfiddle.net/wJYjH).. Would be thankful if you can check. I am using WP plugin Contact Form 7, maybe this could do problem?

Comment: I did that, and changed .prop to .attr - but now all my fields gets disabled, when I clicked on that radio.. aaaa i am banging my head with this all day.. do you have any other idea please?

Comment: nope.. do I need to change anything else? Which attributes does the radio need (id, name, value- anything else?).. and this code i put between <script>..</script> ?

Comment: Well, this should work. I dunno why it isn't. Here's a jsbin with your exact html as taken from your website. And it works here: http://jsbin.com/ukabir/2/edit ... I am not sure what else to do. Better (smarter) people are needed, I guess

Comment: Also add a `.val('')` after `.prop('disabled',true)` in the click event, for better functionality. And now if you could accept this answer, I could do with some reputationz

Comment: It was here:.wpcf7-form--ontrol.. instead of control. Thank you very much, you made my day and that focus is very good. Now I just need to add something, that clears data from one field if user decide in the mean time, that he wants to fill out other field :) thank you again, hope that i will have the possibility to return you the fava!

Comment: The `.val('')` is precisely for that.

Comment: cool. i put blank space in it and it is working. perfect.. but I dont know whats with that WP or JS or whatever.. In your JS Bin it works when you switch between that other gets disabled again.. on my site it doesent.. but I think that this is with CSS. Otherwise, the functionality is what I searched for. Thanks again.. edit: yes, it was CSS

Comment: I updated my code a bit, but now it is not working anymore. Can someone help me please.. the http://jsfiddle.net/wLFKD/2/ is here.. At first I want to disable all inputs, and on clicking the radio button to enable them and focus on first one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This markup:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text1"/>
<input type="text" id="id1" disabled="disabled"/><br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text2"/>  
<input type="text" id="id2" disabled="disabled"/>​
```

and this script:

```
$('input[name="radioknof"]').on('click', function(){            
    $(this).next().prop('disabled',false).siblings('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
});
```

results in what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/uefAK/

Comment: Hmm.. I cant get it to work because I use WP plugin Contact Form 7, and I cannot give disabled="disabled" to the input field. Is there any workaround?

Comment: you can disable them manually in the script with `$('#id1,#id2').prop('disabled', true);` or `$('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', true);` or equivalent (like in Abhilash's answer)

Comment: this way it goes.. but then your script for switching does not work.. I dont know whats wrong..

Comment: yes, I have now 3 working in JS fiddle.. But this damn Contact Form 7.. But I need it because of DB. Maybe this does not work because the class and name is assigned automatically to the text box. can you check please (http://transferji.org) - thanks

Comment: The DOM structure is a bit different on the actual page. The script from this fiddle should work better: http://jsfiddle.net/wJYjH/

Comment: hey, thanks man, but this stil does not work on my site? Do you happen to know what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why not, another solution that **doesn't require Javascript**?

```
// HTML
<form>
    <div>
        <input id="trigger-1" type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text1"/>
        <label for="trigger-1"><input type="text" id="input-1" /></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="trigger-2" type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text2"/>
        <label for="trigger-2"><input type="text" id="input-2" /></label>
    </div>
</form>​


// CSS, but just for styling, it doesn't have functional meaning :)
form {padding: 2%}
div {margin: 1em 0}
input[type='radio'] {cursor: pointer;}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nUWcF/