# Trouble shooting jquery enable/disable text box based on radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are a number of posts on how to enable a text field based on a radio button selection using jquery. Source:[Disable/enable text field with radio button (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231991/disable-enable-text-field-with-radio-button-jquery)

I've zero experience with javascript, and I cannot get any of these examples to work.

I've tried multiple examples provided via jfiddle, but they don't work on my app.

So, a checklist: 
1) javascript works in general, because I have copy&pasted a date picker widget which works just fine. 
2) I've got my   tags wrapping the snippets of code
3) Whether it's in the body or the header makes no difference.

Here's the example code I'm using
In a view (this is codeigniter)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
//enable a box if the radio button is selected

$('input[name="radioknof"]').on('click', function() {
$(this).next().prop('disabled',false).siblings('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
});
</script>

<input type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text1"/>
<input type="text" id="id1" disabled="disabled"/><br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text2"/>  
<input type="text" id="id2" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Obviously I'm missing something as simple as a syntax error... but I cannot for the life of me see it. What I don't understand is why jfiddle works 100%, and on my local server it doesn't.

(The boxes are both disabled regardless of the radio button selection)
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out.... as I mentioned I have zero experience, so I just went back to the jfiddle example and looked at the underlying code and found the extra lines `$(window).load(function(){` with the closing `});`at the end.

Complete code below.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'>  </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',true);
            $('input[name=radioknof]').on('click', function()
                {            
                    $(this).next().prop('disabled',true).siblings('input[type=text]').prop('disabled',false);
                }
            );
        });             
    </script>

    <input type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text1" />
    <input type="text" id="id1" disabled="true"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="radioknof" value="text2"/>  
    <input type="text" id="id2"/> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">` with code inside it. You should have something more like:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    // put your code in here
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Either that or use a `load` Event inside your `<head>`. You cannot define `src` and also put code inside the `<script>` tag. I would personally use another external `src` for your other tag as well, so it gets cached into your Client's Browser memory.

Comment: Nope. nothing changes.  I get the point about the tags, and I'll use another external source when I get it working. But so far no improvement. both boxes remain disabled.

Comment: Try using `$('#id')` selectors, just to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The disabled HTML form input attribute doesn't take a parameter. You either have it set or you don't, so in order to fix your code, remove the disabled attribute altogether when you want to enable that field.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not familiar enough with javascript to understand that. You're referring to `.prop('disabled',true);` I presume?

Comment: Not quite sure why you say form... there isn't one in this example...?

Comment: `<input>` tags are form elements, which is why I referred to them as such. Glad to see you figured it out below though!